# Copy row to another sheet via for loop google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am below a newbie and have tried this code several ways and I just can't seem to figure out what is going on.

What I am trying to do is copy any new lines that get added to one sheet (`Source`) to another sheet (`Target`). There is a column (7) that is there to indicate not to copy that row from the `Source` to the `Target`, and is set to `CP` when the program runs through and copies to the `Target`.

The code below seems to work and copy to the `Target` with the exception that it copies every row from the `Source` every time I run it, even when the Source rows have been set to `CP` in col 7 (`CP` means copied if you are wondering).

Any help would be appreciated in helping me figure this out. I've banged my head against the desk a few times already but that does not seem to help either  .

```js
function copyRowToTarget() {

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Source')
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Target') 
  var startRow = 2; 
  var sSLastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var con = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 7, sSLastRow); //col that indicates if it should be copied or not
  var conVals = con.getValues(); //con values
  var rangetocopy = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sSLastRow, 6); 
  var rowstocopy = rangetocopy.getValues(); //values to copy
     

  for (var i = 1; i < conVals.length; i++){
    if (conVals[i] !== "CP"){
      targetSheet.appendRow(rowstocopy[i]);
    }
    sourceSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue("CP");

  }
}
```

Comment: What is startRow?  Why is it in your code but not being used in any of the getRange() methods that are used to read data?

Comment: My guess is that this `sourceSheet.getRange(1, 7, sSLastRow)` should be this `sourceSheet.getRange(startRow,7,sourceSheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1,1)`  and your loop should start at zero.

Comment: conVals[i] should be conVals[i][0] because even one column or or one row is still a two dimensional array

Comment: OMG!!! That last one worked. Setting conVals[i][0] did it. Thank you soooooooo much!!!

Comment: I also changed sourceSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue("CP") to sourceSheet.getRange(startRow + i-1, 7).setValue("CP") as it was adding an extra CP at the bottom the sheet. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copyRowToTarget() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Source')
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Target') 
  const startRow = 2; 
  const vals=ssh.getRange(startRow, 6, ssh.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, 2).getValues();
  vals.forEach((v,i)=>{
    if (v[1] != "CP"){
      tsh.appendRow([v[0]]);
      ssh.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue("CP");
    }
  });
}
```

I tested this version:

```
function copyRowToTarget() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2') 
  const startRow = 2; 
  const vals=ssh.getRange(startRow, 6, ssh.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, 2).getValues();
  vals.forEach((v,i)=>{
    if (v[1] != "CP"){
      tsh.appendRow([v[0]]);
      ssh.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue("CP");
    }
  });
}
```

Works fine:

Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 13 | 10 | 27 | 1 | 17 | CP | 8 | 25 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 12 | 16 | 26 | 1 | CP | 25 | 14 | 5 |
| 2 | 8 | 10 | 25 | 6 | 20 | CP | 10 | 3 | 0 |
| 16 | 15 | 21 | 12 | 2 | 1 | CP | 9 | 15 | 0 |
| 29 | 10 | 9 | 10 | 25 | 23 | CP | 27 | 29 | 6 |
| 28 | 24 | 4 | 13 | 2 | 26 | CP | 23 | 19 | 19 |
| 29 | 17 | 3 | 0 | 9 | 1 | CP | 3 | 27 | 15 |
| 20 | 8 | 7 | 15 | 28 | 26 | CP | 10 | 24 | 13 |
| 27 | 16 | 29 | 2 | 25 | 14 | CP | 21 | 4 | 12 |

Sheet2:

|  |
| --- |
| 17 |
| 1 |
| 20 |
| 1 |
| 23 |
| 26 |
| 1 |
| 26 |
| 14 |
| 13 |